# Option to Alphabetize StackExchange Footer

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, stackexchange-2.0, design

Area 51 and the Stack Exchange in general appear to be developing swimmingly. There's currently Twenty-Eight separate sites in the Stack Exchange footer, and I expect that will only increase over time.

I think it would be useful to have an option somewhere to better organize the sites in the footer (possibly on a per-user basis). I understand that the sites currently in the footer are in mostly order of matriculation, with the oldest sites coming first.

However, this threatens to become increasingly irksome to navigate when you are on one of the stack exchange sites and want to move to another (for instance, gaming to game dev, or math to statistics) since there is little rhyme or reason to the sites position (personally, I had to doublecheck and go through the list twice to be able to assure myself that "stats.stackexchange" was even in the list to begin with) within the footer.

Would it be possible to give users the option to personally organize the footer, such as by alphabetizing it, or listing the sites in descending order of the user's rep?

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes? I'd appreciate an understanding of *why* this suggestion is not useful rather than simply being downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: I have to agree the footer will essentially become useless if order is not established

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the stackexchange drop-down *all sites* list, which already does this (orders by rep, as long as you have 200+ rep on each site)?

The dropdown is ambiently sorted by your rep level on each site, so you do in effect have a list of sites where you participate at the top.

[image]

You must have a minimum of **200 rep** on any given site to have it appear in anything other than random order, though.

Comment: I really like that sorting, but could you please lower the minimum?

Comment: But what about the use-case where someone (i.e., me) has a question that does not fit with any of his present SE accounts but recalls there's a SE site for it? Like, I have a very WordPress-specific question and I remember "Hey, isn't there a WP SE site? Maybe I can check that out." So I go to SO, look at the footer, but what greets me is an unsorted list of SE sites. I find 'wordpress' in between 'apple' and 'physics', at the third row, after a linear, O(n) scan. Could've done better if only the data is sorted...

Comment: @sky try http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list